# Flutter - Keyboard not showing when TextFormField is selected

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am currently experiencing an issue where the keyboard does not appear when I select any `TextFormField` widgets inside of a `Form` widget. This is the code for the form, which is inside of my `CreateAccountForm` Stateful widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:sign_up_page/constants.dart';

class CreateAccountForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateAccountFormState createState() => _CreateAccountFormState();
}

class _CreateAccountFormState extends State<CreateAccountForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          CustomTextFormField(
            labelText: "Email",
            keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
          ),
          Spacer(),
          CustomTextFormField(labelText: "Full name"),
          Spacer(),
          CustomTextFormField(
            labelText: "Password",
            isPassword: true,
          ),
          Spacer(),
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              print("Get started button pressed");
            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            color: blueMaterialColor.shade100,
            shape: defaultRectangularButtonShape,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  "Get started",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTextFormField extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomTextFormField({
    @required this.labelText,
    this.isPassword = false,
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
  });

  final String labelText;
  final bool isPassword;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;

  @override
  _CustomTextFormFieldState createState() => _CustomTextFormFieldState();
}

class _CustomTextFormFieldState extends State<CustomTextFormField> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: widget.labelText, labelStyle: inputLabelStyleUnselected),
      style: inputTextStyle,
      obscureText: widget.isPassword,
      keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
    );
  }
}
```

This is a screenshot, which shows the cursor inside of the email `TextFormWidget`, but without the keyboard showing up:

[image: A screenshot of the app running on an iPhone 11. The keyboard does not show even when a TextFormWidget is selected.]

You can view all of the code for the project on my Github branch here: https://github.com/Jordan-Gillard/sign_up_page/tree/bug/fixing_keyboard_not_showing

Comment: Are you using a simulator or an actual device ? @Jordan Gillard

Comment: I'm using a simulator. I just tried on Android, and it works on the Android simulator. Ugh. Some things I wish I could just fix with code. If I fix this by messing with the simulator, Ill post an answer with what I did.

Comment: Your simulator probably has the option to Connect to hardware keyboard checked, you can fix it by turning it off, I posted an answer @Jordan Gillard

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are running on a `Simulator`, your `Simulator` definitely has the `Connect Hardware Keyboard` enabled. You can fix the issue by disabling the feature.

I provided images to guide on how to do that below:

1. Select your simulator and click on the `Hardware` tab.
2. On the `Hardware` tab, select the `Keyboard` option.
3. Uncheck the `Connect Keyboard Hardware` option to enabling toggling an actual keyboard on the `Simulator`

Check the Images provided below for more visual description :)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I had called `enableFlutterDriverExtension()` in main.dart.  Removing this fixed the isssue.

Comment: Can you please explain why this happens? Will I have to remove this piece of code every time I want to build a release version of the app?

Answer (score 2):

If you use ios simulator, the menu tab is I/O.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCxu0.png)

Answer (score 1):

the solution is simple

1. wrap your textFields and buttons in a separate column widget
2. then wrap that column with Form() and give formKey

eg.

```
 Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 21),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return '';
                      }
                      return null;
                    }, 
                  ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to click `I/O -> Keyboard -> Toggle Software Keyboard`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, you have to add in your scaffold "resizeToAvoidBottomInset"

```
Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        body: ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a CustomTextField where I had set the default value of "keyboardType" to TextInputType.none, and was wondering why it doesn't work. :)