# Keyboard is not showing on clicking on TextFormField in Flutter Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm using TextFormField in flutter app. In my app everywhere It's working fine, But just in one screen it giving me an error. When I click on TextFormField then Keyboard opened and instantly hide automatically. Here is my code for TextFormField.

```
TextFormField(
  controller: offerController,
  maxLines: 1,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  style: GoogleFonts.arimo(
    textStyle: const TextStyle(
      color: Color(ColorConstants.TEXT_COLOR_GREY),
      fontSize: 14.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    ),
  ),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: InputBorder.none,
    enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
    hintText: "Add the Offer Value",
    hintStyle: GoogleFonts.arimo(
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Color(ColorConstants.COLOR_BFBFBF),
        fontSize: 14.0,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onTap(){
   FocusNode.requestFocus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your textFormField.

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
inputFormatters: [
  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
],
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, if you use the ios simulator, you can see this link  [Flutter - Keyboard not showing when TextFormField is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62847402/10683162)